# socket_connect / fsockopen() Connection Refused (111)

Tags: php, c++, sockets

I wrote a PHP script that simply connects to my C++ server via `socket_connect()` on a certain port that it's listening on. My C++ server can accept clients from C++ clients and other services, such as http:///canyouseeme.org which is a tool to check if the port you're using is open. These services work.

However, the PHP script which is run on *HostGator* no matter if the server is up or not, cannot connect to my C++ server and I have absolutely no idea why. Yes, I've unblocked the port via my router. This is the error:

> Warning: socket_connect(): unable to connect [111]: Connection refused in /home4/user/public_html/porttest.php on line 15
>   socket_connection() failed. Reason: () Connection refused Closing socket.

Here's my PHP script:

```
<?php
  $host = "<EXTERNAL IP TO C++ SERVER HERE>";
  $port = "<TCP PORT C++ SERVER IS USING HERE>";

  /* Create a TCP/IP socket. */
  $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
  if ($socket === false) {
      echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
  } else {
      echo "SOCKET OK.\n";
  }

  echo "Attempting Connection...";
  $result = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port);
  if($result == false){
    echo "socket_connection() failed.\nReason: ($result) " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) . "\n";
  }
  else{
    echo "CONNECTION OK.\n";
  }

  socket_close($socket);
  echo "Closing socket.";
?>
```

My C++ server is run on Windows. I'm fairly certain the *HostGator* web server is run on Linux. Why can't it connect to my C++ server yet other services can? Does it has something to do with the fact I'm on a wireless connection?

*HostGator* technical support does not know what's wrong.

Comment: Usually - connection refused - means - there is nothing listening on the given address port or the firewall is sending RST on SYN. Can you verify doing `neststat` whether a socket is already listening on your c++ server. Note: most of the times not doing appropriate `ntohs` for port number could end up server listening on different port than you wanted (and so also for connect). So check that as well

Comment: The problem turned out to be with Host Gator blocking out going ports, which I must make a ticket for.

Answer (score 0):

"`111 refused to a remote SMTP server`" was in my case caused by a source server firewall blocking the SMTP connection.

It can help to whitelist destination IP or disable SMTP blocking/whitelist user in ConfigServerFirewall (if used) configuration:

```
SMTP_BLOCK = off
SMTP_ALLOWUSER = usernamehere
```